# httpd (no pid file) not running while restarting apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, web-server, httpd

I am working on ubuntu. I got the error messages while try to restart apache.

```
root@XXX:/etc/init.d# sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                              apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name,                                                               using xxx.xxx.xx.xxx for ServerName
httpd (no pid file) not running
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name,                                                               using xxx.xxx.xx.xxx for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

I got the following message when tried `netstat -pant`

```
tcp        0   0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          32748       9950/httpd

tcp      429      0 xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:80       xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxxx    CLOSE_WAIT  0          0
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `lsof -i :80` {check if the parameter is correct). It's listing all the application that are listening on port 80.

Also try to run apache2 {directly the executable} to check what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Just kill apache pid ( i think that its 'kill 9950' )

and then try 
/etc/init.d/apache2 start

Comment: I have tried it but apache2 start shows same errors

Comment: You need to kill what ever is running on port 80...
The PID complaint is only because you are trying to stop something that hasnt written a pid.. ( not important )

Is this an aptitude install? Or a precompiled version of apache?

Comment: If kill does not work you can also try 'killall -9 httpd', verify using 'ps -C httpd' that process got killed and then use '/etc/init.d/apache2 start'.

Comment: After upgrade from High Sierra to Catalina in MacOs, same thing, seems like a bug. After running `sudo killall -9 httpd`, the built-in apache stop serving. `sudo apachectl stop` never stop it, but `sudo apachectl start` will start it.

Comment: Realizing that apachectl will auto-restart each time I killall httpd. The way I stopped it was to unload it from launchctl: `sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`

Answer (score 1):

From some other people's post, it's due to some applcation binds port 80, so just issue 'killall httpd' then a 'apachectl start' to make things alll normal again.

Answer (score 0):

use `pgrep apache2` to get to get the process list

Comment: And after that, then what?

Answer (score 0):

At least for me, this problem was caused by having installed nginx in the same session (and changed my mind and installed apache instead). Once I uninstalled nginx, turned off the the apache web client, started it again, and then restarted (not reload or start, restart) the service, it worked well.